# folder name "examples" is not visible in localhost folder listing

Tags: google-chrome, xampp, localhost

If I change folder name from any to `examples` - it's not visible in localhost folder listing.

address-bar: `localhost`

```
Index of /
example // visible
examp // visible
any other name // visible, but:
examples // not visible
```

I'm using xampp and chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to comment out this line:

```
ProxyPass /examples ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/examples smax=0 ttl=60 retry=5
```

in `xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf`